# How to make the reset button work properly for canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Need help with making the reset button work properly. When you click the reset button i need it to reposition  the triangle back to the middle of the canvas. Also how can I get the blue circle to move with both the big triangle and the smaller red triangle. There is another obvious problem but I want to focus on just these two problems to start.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CPSC Assignment 6</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="a6.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="setUp();">
        <h2>The Adventure of Terry the Triangle</h2>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid black;">
        </canvas><br>
        <input type="button" id="reset" value="reset" onclick="reset();">
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let canvasLength = 500;
let mid = canvasLength / 2;

let x = mid;
let y = mid; 
let dir;

function setUp() {
    drawTerry(x, y, dir);
    addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 37) {
            x = x - 10;
            if(x <= 10) {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasLength, canvasLength)
                x = 0;
            }
        }

        if (event.keyCode == 38) {
            y = y - 10;
            if(y <= 10) {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasLength, canvasLength)
                y = 0;
            }

        }

        if (event.keyCode == 39) {
            x = x + 10;
            if(x <= 10) {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasLength, canvasLength)
                x = 0;
            }
        }

        if (event.keyCode == 40) {
            y = y + 10;
            if(y <= 10) {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasLength, canvasLength)
                y = 0;
            }
        }


        drawTerry(x, y, dir);
    })
}

function reset() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasLength, canvasLength);
    setUp();
}

function drawTerry(x, y, dir) { 
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.rotate(-30 * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 50);
    ctx.rotate(60 * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 50);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.rotate(-30 * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 8);
    ctx.rotate(60 * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 8);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();

    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(mid, mid + 25, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: `console.log()` the `x` and `y` variables within the `setUp()` function. Open the JavaScript console to see their values. What are the values when you first start the program? What are the values after moving the triangle around and clicking 'reset'?

Comment: how do i make the circle inside the triangle move with the triangle?